# uncaught type error number is not a function for custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a custom widget (a button) that is opening another custom widget (dialog).  The first widget (button is displaying fine, but I'm getting the subject error when I try to open the second widget.

Button Widget (myButton.js)

```
define([ 
  "custom/myDialog.js",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", 
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dojo/text!./myButton.html",
  "dijit/form/Button"
], function(myDiag, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, declare, myTemplate) {
  return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
    templateString: myTemplate,

    OpenDialog: function(){
      var d = new myDiag({});//uncaught type error: number is not a function
      d.myDialog.startup();
      d.myDialog.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Button Template (myButton.html)

```
<div>
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:OpenDialog">click for dialog</button>

</div>
```

Dialog Widget (myDialog.js)

```
define([ 
  "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin", 
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", 
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dojo/text!./myDialog.html",
  "dijit/form/Select",
  "dijit/Dialog"
], function(_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, declare, myTemplate) {
  return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
    templateString: myTemplate,
  });
});
```

Dialog Template (myDialog.html)

```
<div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog"  title="Mark Ticket" data-dojo-attach-point="myDialog">
<select id="selectReach" style="width: 150px; height:20px;" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select">
                <option selected="selected">IV</option>
                <option>IVA</option>
                <option>IVB</option>
                <option>IVD</option>
                <option>IVE</option>
                <option>V</option>
                </select>
                </div>
</div>
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpsQ4GHpzxIQzF4sh65z)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `require myDialog` statement in myButton.js should be `'custom/myDialog'`, not `'custom/myDialog.js'`:

```
define([ 
    "custom/myDialog",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase", 
    ...
```

With the .js on there, it's trying to load myDialog.html from the Google CDN, where it obviously can't find it, thus making myDialog.js fail.

It's standard practice to require other modules from the same package by using "relative module identifiers" (to make sure you're loading the right module and increase portability), so you should change it to `'./myDialog'` if that applies to your situation. See the "writing portable modules" section of [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/).

Other notes: the `window.location` method you're using for your package declaration only works if the user is looking at `directory/`, not `directory/index.html`.

You'll want to remove the `id="SelectReach"` from myDialog.html, as you'll get a "this ID is already registered" error on trying to open (create) the dialog more than once. Avoid using IDs in templates at all. Maybe use a class and `query` if you need to reference the select input.

And you have a trailing comma in myDialog.js, line 11.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and other suggestions -- this helps alot